# PHP - How do I filter jQuery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

My script is using PHP, and I'm using jQuery autocomplete for a webform to register on events. The jQuery works on the `name` textfield, and complete all the other textfields after selecting the name.
However, my database stores all records for past events. For example, Susan Boyle had participated 5 of my previous event, and the `name` textfield will show 5 Susan Boyle when I type `Susan`. How do I filter out same names?

My jQuery codes:

```
  $('input.item-autocomplete').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
  $.ajax({
  url:"ajax_reg.php",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{
    'name' : ui.item.value,
    'action' : 'get_fulldata'
  },
  success:function(data){
    $("#mobile1").val(data.mobile1);
    $("#mobile2").val(data.mobile2);
    $("#email").val(data.rt_email);
    $("#tf1").val(data.tf1);
    $("#tf2").val(data.tf2);
    $("#tf3").val(data.tf3);
    }
   });
});
```

Updates: Sorry I forgot about the SQL codes, I'm writing the SQL in another php file . (SQL codes adjax_reg.php)

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$action = empty($_GET['action'])?'':$_GET['action'];
if(empty($name)){
exit('No data');
}
require_once("../winphplib/kernel.php");
require_once ('../winphplib/dbconnect_egen.php');

if($action=='get_name'){
    $sqlquery = "SELECT rt_name FROM reg_ticket WHERE rt_name LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 15";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die(mysql_error());
    while($myrow = MySQL_fetch_array($result)){
        $data[] = strtoupper($myrow['rt_name']);
    }
}elseif($action=='get_fulldata') {
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM reg_ticket WHERE rt_name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if(count($data)>0){
    list($data['mobile1'], $data['mobile2']) = explode("-", $data['rt_contact']);
    list($data['tf1'], $data['tf2'], $data['tf3']) = explode("-", $data['rt_ic']);
}

}
mysql_free_result($result); 
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You need to post your PHP code and give us a little more context of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: i'd suggest you do that in the PHP, not in the jquery - as your database grows, you'll be sending large amounts of data which just gets filtered out. share how the PHP works, and we might be able to give you an idea of how to do that.

Comment: he is doing it in php. the javascript calls the php

Comment: In your PHP you are doing a sql request to get your data? If yes, just group by name maybe? You should post your php to be sure :)

Comment: Yes, I'm writing in PHP , and the jQuery calls the php file that contains my SQL commands. Just updated in my thread, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `users` on the criteria that they participated in at least an event. You are probably joining `users` with `events`, but you need to filter `users` based on their `participation`. Assuming that you are using the following tables:

> users(id, mobile1, mobile2, email, tf1, tf2, tf3)
>
> events(id, name)
>
> participations(id, user_id, event_id)

you would need a query like this:

```
select id, mobile1, mobile2, email, tf1, tf2, tf3
from users
where exists (select 1
              from participations
              where users.id = participation.user_id)
and users.name like '%Susan%'
```

This will return a record for each user, containing the search text, who has participated at at least one event, giving you the columns you need.

EDIT

I have taken a look at your edited question and there are a lot of problems to be fixed.

#### Avoid using SELECT * in a query

Problems:

- you might have very large data which could waste a lot of memory and time
- you might be returning confidential data to users

Use a column list in your select clause to make sure you only select what you need:

```
select mobile1, mobile2, rt_contact, tf1, tf2, tf3, rt_ic ...
```

will fix this.

#### Fix your problem

You will have to use the [distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword

```
select distinct mobile1, mobile2, rt_contact, tf1, tf2, tf3, rt_ic ...
```

this will select `distinct` values, but if you have inconsistencies, that is, different attributes with the same names for the same person, then you will have several records returned.

#### Auto complete will not work without LIKE

You will have to use `LIKE` and `%...%` as in the `if` if you want to `select` users whose `name` contains the text you have passed. Also, it would not hurt to `select` the `name` as well and possibly the `id`, if the `name` is not unique.

#### mysql_ functions are deprecated

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead.

#### Never use user input as it is in a query

This is prone to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and it is very easy for hackers to do harm to your database or even load data they are not qualified to load. Use parameterized queries with PDO, or escape the parameters.

#### Do not write [Spaghetti](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spaghetti%20code) code

Your code is easier to maintain if you separate the part dealing with databases from the engine part from the view part.

#### Normalize your database

Databases which are not in [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rarely function well, they are difficult to maintain, are prone to [redundancy](https://www.defit.org/data-redundancy/) and [inconsistency](https://www.quora.com/What-is-data-inconsistency-1) and they usually do not perform well.

Comment: I only had 1 table to store the data actually, that's why it cause many `names` redundancy

Comment: Thanks for the help! `DSITINCT` works for my problem. However, its already very hard for me to alter my database, since it was passed over for years, and had too many records.

Comment: @hatched altering the database would consist of creating new tables, dynamically copying all the records from the initial database and refactoring the application code to work with the new schema. All the difficulties in migrating the data come from inconsistencies and redundancies, which should be fixed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script, you just need to tweak your SQL query, by adding a `GROUP BY` clause.

I haven't seen your query, but something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN artists ON events.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE artist like :searchterm
GROUP BY artists.artist_name
```